# How to convert const Eigen::VectorXcf to Eigen::VectorXcf?

Tags: eigen

I want to convert the pointer to `const VectorXcf` to `VectorXcf` in eigen library. I tried `const_cast<VectorXcf>` but it did not work. Following is the error log:

> ```
> error: invalid conversion from 'const Vector2cf* {aka const
> Eigen::Matrix<std::complex<float>, 2, 1>*}' to 'Eigen::Vector2cf* {aka
> Eigen::Matrix<std::complex<float>, 2, 1>*}' [-fpermissive]
> ```

Comment: You should provide a [mcve]. From the error message you seem to actually try to convert something involving pointers.

Answer (score 2):

Can you please show exactly what didn't work for you? I have MCVE  taht works both in Visual Studio 2015 and gcc 6.3.0 (mingw) compiled with `-Wall`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Eigen/Core>

using namespace Eigen;

int main()
{
    typedef VectorXcf T;

    T mat(10);

    const T& matConstRef = mat;
    T* nc = const_cast<T*>(&matConstRef);
    nc->setConstant(T::Scalar(3.4));
    std::cout << *nc << "\n\n";
    Map<T> map = Map<T>(const_cast<T::Scalar*>(matConstRef.data()), matConstRef.rows(), matConstRef.cols());
    map << 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9;
    std::cout << map << "\n\n";
    return 0;
}
```

It compiles without any warnings and gives the expected result.